# Live installer not using hostname provided by DHCP server in automated install

Tags: 18.04, dhcp, preseed, hostname, ubiquity

I'm running a local network with an Ubuntu server and 20 other machines on it.

As I want to install a customized Ubuntu 18.04.1 version on all of them, I already created a modified live image and a preseed file for this purpose, which all works fine with one exception:

The machines all have to receive a specific and unique hostname. Therefore, I removed any preseed information regarding the hostname, hoping that this would make the live installer ask me to enter one, but this only seems to work for the netinstall version (which, due to the lack of an internet connection in that network, is not an option for me).

I then went on and found out that the DHCP server (ISC in my case) could be used for populating the hostname during the installation process, so I added the following entry to my dhcpd.conf:

```
host ws1 {
    hardware ethernet XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX;
    fixed-address 172.24.1.1;
    option host-name "ubuntu-ws1";
}
```

Soon I had to find out that this somehow didn't seem to work either, because the machines simply get the default hostname "ubuntu", while they are getting the right address (172.24.1.1) assigned.

This effectively leaves me with two options: using a separate preseed file for each machine or changing the respective hostnames manually after installing. As this doesn't seem like a proper solution to me, I'm interested in getting one of the preceding methods working.

I don't know whether I'm missing something or receiving the hostname from the DHCP server is currently not working with the live installer.

Comment: I suffer from exactly the same problem. Looking inside the ubiquity sources it seems that there is no support for it.